# imagestring issue with PHP 5.3

Tags: php

Here is my function:

> imagestring($destination, 4, 68, 90,
>   $text, black);

That function had always worked for the past 2 years, but since I updated PHP to 5.3, the following error message is displayed:

Warning: `imagestring()` expects parameter 6 to be long, string given in /home/... on line ...

What is wrong and what correction do I need to bring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
imagestring($destination, 4, 68, 90, $text, black);
```

Unless you have defined `black` as a constant, this is the wrong syntax anyway. This should've been wrong for the past two years, but I suppose PHP's error checking became stricter in 5.3 and/or warnings became enabled. It just happened to produce the desired result through sheer coincidence. The last parameter is actually defined as:

> `int $color`
>   A color identifier created with [`imagecolorallocate()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorallocate.php).

So, you can't just pass in the string `"black"` (note the quotes), you need to pass in the result of a call to `imagecolorallocate`, like:

```
imagestring($destination, 4, 68, 90, $text, imagecolorallocate($destination, 0, 0, 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

When you pass `black` there, PHP will look for a global constant `black`. If `black` is not defined, it will map it to a string `"black"`.

Try passing `imagecolorallocate($destination, 0, 0, 0)` there.

Comment: It had alwars worked before; how do I get this fixed?

Answer (score 1):

The signature for `imagestring()` is

> bool imagestring ( resource $image , int $font , int $x , int $y , string $string , int $color )

It's possible you meant to use `"black"` instead of `black` which if cast to an `int` is `0` which may just be the integer colour identifier for black. Perhaps PHP 5.3 added type checking to the argument values.

**Edit:** Taking even more liberty with my guesswork, I'd say you've disable `E_NOTICE` error reporting and the undefined constant `black` was evaluated as the string `"black"`. If PHP 5.3 *did* introduce tighter constraints on argument types, this may have *just worked* in previous versions.

It's best to be specific though and use [`imagecolorallocate()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorallocate.php)

```
$black = imagecolorallocate($destination, 0, 0, 0);
```